# Concavity about Maximization question

Tags: calculus, optimization, self-learning

In maximization problem, if objective function $f(x,y)=ax-y$ is linear (concave, and also convex), does any optimal solution $(x^*,y^*)$ exist? Because in continuous time, infinite horizon control problem, objective function must be concave or strictly concave. Then, if I have Linear objective function, Socs does not satisfied. Right?

Comment: Think of the constraints.

Comment: Constraint is $\dot{x}=(a-b)x -2\sqrt{y}$ what do you mean?@RodrigodeAzevedo